# CSS Mask not working on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

I'm trying to show a SVG image using mask but in Firefox it isn't appearing. My CSS class is as follows:

```
.myClass {
    -webkit-mask: url('../img/arrow-down.svg') no-repeat 100% 100%;
    mask: url('../img/arrow-down.svg') no-repeat 100% 100%;
    background: rgba(67, 67, 67, 0.8);
    width: 1.15em;
    height: 1em;
}
```

And html code is just a simple:

```
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

In chrome, my masked arrow-down.svg is showing nicely but in firefox a div with specified background is appearing. Any idea on how to solve my problem?

Comment: @Kaiido: Are you sure that masks work in FF with external SVG? Read on Can I Use sometime back that it works in FF only with inline SVG. I had even mentioned it in the docs [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/3721/clipping-and-masking#t=201607290458575374941). If you can give me links of it working with external SVG, I will change the docs also.

Comment: @harry I'm sure masks work in FF with external SVG. You are misinterpreting the canIUse result. It's trying to say that mask-image doesn't work but SVG masks (including external ones) do work.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Ah yeah, that ID part seems to be the one that is missing. I tried earlier without that and it didn't work, one other user (think the id was Kaiido) also confirmed this and that's why I assumed this to be the case. Thanks for clarifying. I will update this into the docs also :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mask: url('../img/arrow-down.svg') no-repeat 100% 100%;
```

is invalid. You can't have a mask that's an entire SVG file, it must have a fragment identifier that points to a mask element.

On top of that, Firefox currently doesn't support any additional parameters beyond the url so the `no-repeat 100% 100%` will cause it to fail.

For Firefox what you need is something like this:

```
mask: url('../img/arrow-down.svg#maskelement')
```

where maskelement would be the id of a `<mask>` element within the arrow-down.svg file.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may still be wandering, the following works fine for me, by inserting the encoded svg string as a data uri (not base64!):

```css
.my-class {
  --svg-icon: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,...');
  mask: var(--svg-icon) no-repeat;
  mask-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask: var(--svg-icon) no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
  background-color: currentColor;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
}
```

I was able to pull this off thanks to some nice tutorials/examples by Anthony Fu and Noah Blon:

- [Icons in Pure CSS](https://antfu.me/posts/icons-in-pure-css)
- [Iconify source code](https://github.com/antfu/unocss/blob/main/packages/preset-icons/src/index.ts)
- [Coloring SVGs in CSS Background Images](https://codepen.io/noahblon/post/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images)